# On the use of latter within a sentence, how many does latter refer to

Tags: word-usage

This is my sentence.....

> These include, the manager, an occupational therapist(O.T), an
>   activity coordinator, two mental health practitioners, two mental
>   health nurses and eight health care assistants.

And I want to say...

> The latter two, work twelve hour shifts.

Is this possible or does latter just refer to the last in the list?

Comment: Please look up use cases. Use *later* / *latter* with *former* (single units/ groups/ sets) and *last* with *first* (units in a long list). "The **last** two work twelve hours shifts."

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/latter

Comment: To add up to Kris's comment, I would probably use "the last two categories", to make it clear that you are talking about health nurses and health care assistants and not only the last two assistants, when I interpreted correctly what you meant to say. But that may only be the non-native English speaker speaking and "the last two" may be clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a bit complicated. I would definitely agree with "latter two" *if* the latter two in question are singular (though "last two" is better - I normally only use "latter" to mean the single last item, in this case, the eight health care assistants); for your case, I'm half tempted to say "latter ten" (but, again, it should really be "last ten").

More seriously, "the two last groups" (or "the last two groups") would probably work better. I'd rather use "the two latter groups" over "the latter two groups", but IMHO both are worse than the versions with "last".

Incidentally, you do not need a comma after "latter two" (or any of the clauses I proposed), and not after "they include" either (though a colon would work).

Comment: As oxforddictionaries point out in @Kris's link, *It is not considered good writing style to use **latter** to refer to more than two things.* By which they mean ***former*** and ***latter*** should only be used in the context of a *"list" containing exactly and only **two** elements* (note that *two mental health nurses **and** eight health care assistants* is a list of two elements, each of which happens to be a plural NP).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's basically what i said: I would definitely use that, but I'd rather use "last", and the OP's specific example is wrong even to me. That said, my background is all wrong to perceive "good writing style" well: English is my second language - it's only as good as it is because I spent years reading online posts at 2000 words per minute; but that means I can't perceive that something is wrong (unless there's an obvious spelling or grammatical error) if it happened often enough. Richness of the stimulus, as Language Log would say. (I've deleted the old comment, incidentally.)

Comment: The issue is you used "I would **definitely** agree with **latter two**..."

Comment: @Rathony Will edit to clarify. Sorry.

Comment: You don't need to say sorry. We welcome you to EL&U. :-)

Comment: @January First-of-May: The way I read your answer text, you're saying you'd be happy for OP to use ***latter*** if his list had happened to end with two singular elements - *two mental health practitioners, **a mental health nurse and a health care assistant***. But since the *list* has more than two elements, oxforddictionaries would still say it's bad style to use ***former, latter*** to reference *anything* within such a list.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You read it correctly - I am. Though "last" fits better. (Did you read the clarification? It might have happened after you started typing.)

Comment: As you suspected, I didn't see your edit until after posting my comment(s). I'll reverse my downvote, because you've now clarified your own position (which is much the same as my own). I'm *aware* of the "poor style" perspective, though I don't always observe it myself anyway. But I'd certainly avoid using ***latter*** in OP's context, (I think *the latter **two*** is clunky, regardless of whether those two are singular or plural elements) and your *the last two groups* works well enough for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughts and clarifications, I have read and think I will use, last two. Interesting that latter only works with two in a list and as my list is long, last will be better. Alison